# My jQuery validation is'nt working giving me error on my html php form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, validation

EDIT: This is the error message i'm getting i dont know why its not working

---

As far as I know this **should** work as a locally opened html file, I have a html and php form and I want validation to validate the form to do as says in the code but it doesn't seem to be working, what would be easiest way to fix this?

I've basically just copied over the code over from another page I've done with some minor changed but cant see why its failing like it is, can anyone correct it or give some assistance?

HTML-
Script:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> <script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script> <script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script>
$(function() {
    $("#Message").validate({
        rules: {
            Name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                maxlength: 15
                },
            Email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
                },
            Message: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 10
                 }
    }});

});
                </script>
```

Form:

```
<p><form id="Message" method="POST" action="message.php">
<p>Enter Name: <input id="Name" type="text" name="Name" size="20"></p>
<p>Enter Email: <input id="Email" type="text" name="Email" size="20"></p>
<p>Message: <input id="Message" type="text" name="Message" size"20"></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit"></p>
```

PHP Message.php:

```
<?php

## CONFIG ##

# LIST EMAIL ADDRESS
$recipient = "MYEMAIL";

# SUBJECT (Subscribe/Remove)
$subject = "WebMsg";

# RESULT PAGE
$location = "received.html";

## FORM VALUES ##

$sender = $recipient;

# MAIL BODY
$body .= "Name: ".$_REQUEST['Name']." \n";
$body .= "Email: ".$_REQUEST['Email']." \n";
$body .= "Message: ".$REQUEST['Message']." \n";
# add more fields here if required

## SEND MESSGAE ##

mail( $recipient, $subject, $body, "From: $sender" ) or header( "Location: $location" );

## SHOW RESULT PAGE ##

header( "Location: $location" );
?>
```

and finally the console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function(anonymous function) @ index.html:15v.Callbacks.l @ jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2v.Callbacks.c.fireWith @ jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2v.extend.ready @ jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2A @ jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2
```

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read and anyone who can help!

++

This is the code that is making it error it says EDITED VVVV

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function(anonymous function) @ index.html:15m.Callbacks.j @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2m.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2m.extend.ready @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2J @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
```

Comment: In html code you have two id='Message'. Each element should have unique id.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have a jQuery validation that's not working on my php html form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31775484/i-have-a-jquery-validation-thats-not-working-on-my-php-html-form)

Comment: @user4621032 Thank you i've changed this but I'm still getting the same thing

Comment: your code should work as it is. If jQuery library is loaded before validation plugin and after that javascript

Comment: @user4621032 no clue mate but its not working so i've set it back to
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
but its still not working

Comment: Error says that error is on index.html pade, but you are saying thjat you are using page.php. .